# How to prompt a folder using cmd?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have folder named "user3"

The path is , "c:/users/%username%/easy/user3/"

using cmd I want to open this folder like prompt.

I have tried following batch programs,

```
start "c:/users/%username%/easy/user3/"

start "c:/users/%username%/easy/user3"
```

Both failed to open the folder `user3`

pls help guys..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `start` command, if the first parameter is in quotes, it is taken as the title of the launched command, so you need a dummy spacer:

```
start "" "c:/users/%username%/easy/user3"
```

This will start Explorer in the selected directory, but I would make two further changes:

- Explorer accepts `/` as a directory separator, but not all programs do, so it is always better to use `\`.
- The directory you specify is not necessarily the user's home directory (Windows may be installed on a different drive, and the home directory name is not always the same as the literal user name).

What I recommend is:

```
start "" "%userprofile%\easy\user3"
```

A trailing back-slash is optional.